# How does the 'QQuaternion' rotation work?

Tags: c++, quaternions

I noticed the difference in the rotation of the vector through the [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) between the Qt library and other libraries.

This is the Qt realization.

```
QQuaternion QQuaternion::fromEulerAngles(float pitch, float yaw, float roll)
{
    // Algorithm from:
    // http://www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html#Q60

    pitch = qDegreesToRadians(pitch);
    yaw = qDegreesToRadians(yaw);
    roll = qDegreesToRadians(roll);

    pitch *= 0.5f;
    yaw *= 0.5f;
    roll *= 0.5f;

    const float c1 = std::cos(yaw);
    const float s1 = std::sin(yaw);
    const float c2 = std::cos(roll);
    const float s2 = std::sin(roll);
    const float c3 = std::cos(pitch);
    const float s3 = std::sin(pitch);
    const float c1c2 = c1 * c2;
    const float s1s2 = s1 * s2;

    const float w = c1c2 * c3 + s1s2 * s3;
    const float x = c1c2 * s3 + s1s2 * c3;
    const float y = s1 * c2 * c3 - c1 * s2 * s3;
    const float z = c1 * s2 * c3 - s1 * c2 * s3;
}
```

And this is some library realization:

```
void Quaternion_fromEulerZYX(double eulerZYX[3], Quaternion* output)
{
    assert(output != NULL);
    // Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles
    double cy = cos(eulerZYX[2] * 0.5);
    double sy = sin(eulerZYX[2] * 0.5);
    double cr = cos(eulerZYX[0] * 0.5);
    double sr = sin(eulerZYX[0] * 0.5);
    double cp = cos(eulerZYX[1] * 0.5);
    double sp = sin(eulerZYX[1] * 0.5);

    output->w = cy * cr * cp + sy * sr * sp;
    output->v[0] = cy * sr * cp - sy * cr * sp;
    output->v[1] = cy * cr * sp + sy * sr * cp;
    output->v[2] = sy * cr * cp - cy * sr * sp;
}
```

Note the last three strings. x and y have different signs in the expression.
And the Qt function corresponds to common [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) matrix multiplication, but not the other library's realization.

So, I'm confused. How does the other library work? Because I have the wrong result using non-Qt libraries.

Comment: Well, the rotation angle (derived from component w) is exactly the same (other than the fact that one is a double and the other a float). If they are about different axes (as in roll, pitch, yaw) then they are strictly "Tait-Bryan" angles, rather than Euler angles. Then the angles are far from unique - it depends which order they are applied, whether they are passive (coordinate-transformation) or active (rotation about fixed axes) and which of [0], [1] or [2] components corresponds to which of roll, pitch, yaw.

Comment: The most important fundamental in any physics/dynamics problem is consistent choice of body-frame axis. That will define your rotation for you. As noted above and in the answer, it will then be up to you to ensure your code then implements that choice. A good library will allow you to define the rotation-order and then carry out the rotations based on that choice. Be aware it is not uncommon for other libraries to simply implement a fixed choice of axis in the rotations they provide. Choose your body-frame carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Qt code snippet is using the Tait-Bryan angles to create a quaternion from Euler angles. The Tait-Bryan angles are a specific type of Euler angles, where each rotation occurs about a different axis (x, y, z).

In contrast, the other library might be using a different convention for rotations. For example, it might be using the ZYX Euler angles to create a quaternion, which rotates about the z-axis, then the y-axis, and finally the x-axis. Differences in these conventions can lead to discrepancies in the results.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that you're applying the rotations in the same sequence and order in both libraries. If the other library uses a different convention, you need to adjust your code accordingly to match that convention.

Here's an example of how you might adjust the other library's method to match the Qt library's convention:

```cpp
void Quaternion_fromEulerZYX(double eulerZYX[3], Quaternion* output)
{
    assert(output != NULL);
    // Adjusted to match the Qt library's convention
    double cy = cos(eulerZYX[1] * 0.5);  // yaw
    double sy = sin(eulerZYX[1] * 0.5);  // yaw
    double cr = cos(eulerZYX[2] * 0.5);  // roll
    double sr = sin(eulerZYX[2] * 0.5);  // roll
    double cp = cos(eulerZYX[0] * 0.5);  // pitch
    double sp = sin(eulerZYX[0] * 0.5);  // pitch

    output->w = cy * cr * cp + sy * sr * sp;
    output->v[0] = cy * sr * cp - sy * cr * sp;
    output->v[1] = cy * cr * sp + sy * sr * cp;
    output->v[2] = sy * cr * cp - cy * sr * sp;
}
```

This code adjusts the order of operations to match the Qt library's convention, which may resolve the discrepancy you're seeing. However, you should always ensure to understand the conventions used by any library before using it, as different libraries may have different conventions for quaternion operations.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT